# Invite friends through AS3 facebook canvas iFrame app

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

We are in process of developing an AS3 app (iframe). The users can invite the friends from the custom pop-up (inside flash). 
Currently we are getting the friendlist in the pop-up but cant invite the friends.

Please help with the solution

Got this

```
var dat:Object = new Object();
dat.message = msg;
dat.from = _user_fbid;
dat.to = fid;
dat.title = title;
Facebook.ui('apprequests', dat, callBack);
```

Would give it a try and update. Meanwhile if anyone knows if this is correct.

UPDATE

This worked for me

Comment: what is the problem, you are facing? What have you tried? Which errors occur? What do you mean by "invite"?

Comment: This is a facebook app, sorry didn't mention in the title.we don't know the way to invite the friends. What code to put when user hits the invite button. Had done this earlier in PHP but don't know for AS3

Comment: Looks about right (I don't have a file set up with the API here that I can test quickly). Watch out for a couple of things: if you're testing in the Flash IDE, you won't ever receive the callback (you need a published app, and your page posted at the url configured in the app settings for that to work); and also look for popup blockers killing the popup. The best check is to view the wall of the person you're inviting and see if the request shows up within a minute or two. Also, you need to have gone through FB authentication and had the user approve your app, but you probably know that...

Comment: yeah...but the pop-up blockers wont block this FB pop-up right? I mean this would be like the lightbox kind which usually come at friend invite or share

Comment: Eh... depends on the popup blocker, and the user. On a live app we launched recently in the UK, we were getting about 15% fails on a 'like' popup, which is probably mostly users clicking like and then not noticing that the popup was blocked.

Comment: Doubtful, as it's not actually a popup - just a CSS lightbox. There's no reason a pop up blocker would (or could) detect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 100% client-side code on your part using the AS3 Facebook API: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

The AS3 API is really only a wrapper for the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (you need the JS in the page and you could use ExternalInterface to call its methods just as well, but the the API provides useful shortcuts). Most JS SDK tutorials can be adapted for use in AS3, which is useful because there aren't that many good Flash tutorials around.

This SO question shows how to do this using the JS SDK: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829864/invite-friends-to-facebook-using-javascript-sdk`  The Facebook.UI object in the AS3 API should have an almost identical method.

One issue with all the Facebook API methods is that they change fairly frequently, and tutorials become out of date. Here is what I believe to be the latest docs on using the JS SDK to invite users:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

At the worst, you could call the methods to launch this dialog using ExternalInterface.

Comment: saagardhoke - please post what you tried as an edit to your question, and what result you got - it's quite difficult to discuss code in detail in these comments. I'll edit my answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
var obj:Object = 
        {
            message: "your message",
            filters: ["app_non_users"],//only if you need it
            title: "your title",
            to: ID //if you don't fill this, you can see the friends selector
        };
        Facebook.ui("apprequests", obj, callBackFunctionOrNull, "iframe");
```